# plotting ROC in R with ROCR vs pROC

Tags: r, roc

I am plotting ROCs and measuring partial AUC as a metric of ecological niche model quality. As I am working in R, I am using the ROCR and the pROC packages. I'll settle on one to use, but for now, I just wanted to see how they performed, and if one met my needs better.

One thing that confuses me is that, when plotting a ROC, the axes are as follows:

**ROCR**

```
x axis: 'true positive rate' 0 -> 1
y axis: 'false positive rate', 0 -> 1
```

**pROC**

```
x axis: 'sensitivity' 0 -> 1
y axis: 'specificity' 1 -> 0.
```

But if I plot the ROC using both methods, they look identical.
So I just want to confirm that:

```
true positive rate = sensitivity

false positive rate = 1 - specificity.
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
obs<-rep(0:1, each=50)
pred<-c(runif(50,min=0,max=0.8),runif(50,min=0.3,max=0.6))
plot(roc(obs,pred))

ROCRpred<-prediction(pred,obs)
plot(performance(ROCRpred,'tpr','fpr'))
```

Comment: Read in detail about these performance measures of classifiers: https://learnerworld.tumblr.com/search/performance+measure
Plus you can always use legacy.axis = TRUE to reverse the scale of axes (from increasing to decreasing or vice versa)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To confirm, you are right in that true positive rate = sensitivity and false positive rate = 1 - specificity.  In your example, the order in which you plot components of the ROCR performance object from the `ROCR` package is key.  In the last line, the first performance measure, true positive rate, 'tpr' gets plotted on the y-axis `measure = 'tpr'` and the second performance measure, false positive rate,  is plotted on the x-axis `x.measure = 'fpr'`

```
plot(performance(ROCRpred, measure = 'tpr', x.measure = 'fpr'))
```

Answer (score 13):

Just to say, for the `pROC` package if you include the following in your plot code:

```
plot(roc(obs,pred), legacy.axes = TRUE)
```

then you end up with a reversed x-axis.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know:

```
TPR = sensitivity = TP/(TP/FN) -> y axis: [0, 1]

FPR = 1 - specificity = 1 - (TN/(FP+TN)) -> x axis: [0, 1]
```

But, when the graph shows specificity (true negative rate) in the x-axis then the range is [1, 0].

In both cases, the graph is the same.

You can check it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic)  in wikipedia page.