# ROC plot and axis wrong, randomForest model

Tags: r

I have the below data and I would like to know if I am on the right tracks regarding a random forest model

I run the following randomForest model but when I go to plot the ROC my axis looks off and I believe it could be something to do with my model but cannot find where I have gone wrong. The x-axis starts at 1.0 and not 0....

[image: ROC Curve]

```
fit <- randomForest(as.factor(status) ~ CA.TA + CA.CL + EBIT.TA + CF.TL + WC.TA + WC.S + TL.TA + C.TA,
                    data = train,
                    importance = TRUE,
                    #type = "prob",
                    ntree = 200)

prediction <- NULL
prediction$status_prediction <- as.data.frame(predict(fit, test))
prediction$status_prediction_prob <- predict(fit, test, type = "prob")

prediction <- NULL
prediction$status_prediction <- predict(fit, test)
prediction <- as.data.frame(prediction)
prediction$status_prediction_prob <- predict(fit, test, type = "prob")

library(caret)
confusionMatrix(prediction$status_prediction, test$status)


prediction$status_prediction <- as.numeric(prediction$status_prediction)
library(pROC)
result.roc <- roc(test$status, prediction$status_prediction)
plot(result.roc, print.thres="best", print.thres.best.method="closest.topleft", main = "ROC curve", print.auc = TRUE)
auc(test$status, prediction$status_prediction)
```

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829729/plotting-roc-in-r-with-rocr-vs-proc

Comment: It has to do with what this package uses in x axis. It uses specificity, when other packages use 1 - specificity (false positive rates) and then the axis will start from zero.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The following worked for me;
`plot(roc(test$status,prediction$status_prediction), legacy.axes = TRUE)` and now it starts at zero.

Comment: You simply need to reverse the scale of x-axis. Then, It'll show (1 - specificity) on x-axis with a range of 0 to 1.
Showing (1-specificity) is more popular, however, some tools including R by default do the reverse job. Between, I believe apart from coding, you must focus on conceptual understanding of these. https://learnerworld.tumblr.com/search/performance+evaluation might help you. It talks about various measures, including sensitivity and specificity and which you should you focus on and why?