# Flip ggplot axis so that it makes more sense

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the below plot

[image]

However the axis on the x axis is wrong, the `1` should be on the other side, however the actual plot itself should not move...

I used the following line;

```
ggroc(list(ROC_base = roc_base, ROC_optimised = roc_optimised))
```

I had a similar problem with the base R plot previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131536/roc-plot-and-axis-wrong-randomforest-model). Using `legacy.axes = TRUE` solved the problem but I cannot find a solution in `ggplot`

Comment: *"Flip ggplot axis [...] however the actual plot itself should not move"* I don't understand what you're after. Flipping the axis means you flip the plot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from the ggroc documentation (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/versions/1.11.0/topics/ggroc.roc) it looks like the solution should be the same as your solution with base R. Just add `legacy.axes = TRUE`

Comment: You have no idea how many times I tried to implement the `legacy.axes = TRUE` into my plot and come up with errors and incorrect plots... However, when I do it when you answer the question, it works straight away!

`ggroc(list(ROC_base = roc_base, ROC_optimised = roc_optimised), legacy.axes = TRUE)`  Works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to add `scale_x_reverse()` to your `ggplot`. This will flip the x-axis of the plot so that 1 is to the right and 0 is to the left. I haven't used `ggroc` before, but the normal way to add layers and options like this to a `ggplot` is with a `+`:

```
ggroc(list(ROC_base = roc_base, ROC_optimised = roc_optimised)) +
    scale_x_reverse()
```